# Difference between Plain text input type and Person Name input type in Editext in android

Tags: android, android-widget

When we use EditText widget in Android, then what are the basic difference while using Plain Text input type and Person name input type?

Comment: Its urgent ,dont effect anyone... here

Comment: With PersonName input type, the edit text automatically capitalizes the first letter of each word entered by the user.

Comment: PlainText can be multiline.. i have an editText which i want to be single line ..  I use inputType="textPersonName" my problem is solved.. I think major difference is multiline.  the user can not insert new lines (the enter button is not showed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your input type the softkeyboad display will change dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

There is no real difference between the two. To clarify what I mean when I say no real difference, the Person Name input simply has the attribute `android:inputType="textPersonName"` preset. The person Name edit text will capitalize the first character of every word after the user hits the space button.

It is only to offer some convenience to developers who need to set the `inputType` attribute to EditTex views. You will find some similar preset Text Fields in the Android SDK's ADT. And by using the attribute mentioned above, you can have the same effect on a Plain Text field too.

Answer (score 2):

for person name input  type - single line  edit text

for plain text -multiline edittext box height of the edittext changes based on your data

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)  link, `EditText` can be defined as it is a thin veneer over `TextView` that configures itself to be editable.

1. The inputType PersonName can be given as - `android:inputType="textPersonName"`
2. The inputType Normal Text can be given as  - `android:inputType = "text"`

**Note :** Based on the inputType the softkeyboad display will be changed dynamically.

Comment: @androidDev do u find the solution?